# Is there a phrase that means "the consequence of which if not abiding to it"?

Tags: phrase-request

Is there a phrase that means "the consequence of which if not abiding to it"? This made up phrase is really awkward sounding, because of the part "if not abiding to it", which is like a parenthetical thought that's necessary, and thus ungrammatical. Is there a way to say this naturally?

Here's an example:

> Her parents forced her into an arranged marriage the consequence of
>   which if not abiding to it was death.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In order for that to sound natural (and be grammatical), while keeping it as close to the way you phrased it as possible, you need to move the *which* toward the end of the sentence, add *by* in front of it, and drop the additional pronoun (I'm also going to add a comma, although it's not directly relevant to the syntax). Also note that it's not *abide* ***to*** but *abide* ***by***.

> ✘ Her parents forced her into an arranged marriage the consequence of which if not abiding to it was death.
>
> ✔ Her parents forced her into an arranged marriage, the consequence of not abiding by which was death.

---

This works because it combines the elements of all of these constructions, along with a negation:

> She **abided by** her marriage.
>   Marriage was the thing **by which** she abided.
>   The **consequence of which** was death.

So:

> The **consequence of** [*not* **abiding by**] **which** was death.

Answer (score 0):

I can't think of a single common standard phrase for the meaning you are asking about. I would rewrite the exmaple as:

> Her parents forced her into an arranged marriage, if she broke it she would suffer death.

or

> Her parents forced her into an arranged marriage, if she did not abide by it, she would be killed.

Other cases in which your construction could have been used:

> If law XYZ is broken, the consequence is 5 years in prison.

but better

> The penalty for breaking law XYZ is 5 years in prison.
>
> The consequence for breaking a promise to a friend may be the loss of the friendship.
>
> If one does not abide by the contract terms, the other party may sue.